# Error:- Null Point Exception in NetBeans IDE 8.2

Tags: java, exception, nullpointerexception

Actually I'm developing an attendance Software and for this I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.2. I want to pass data from one frame to another and then insert all together in MYSQL. These are the pictures of Both frames through which I want data to pass and save it to MYSQL.

I want after entering all the required data by the user and when user clicks to next button. `FinalRegister` frame should appear and for that this is what i had done behind next button

```java
  private void    jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    FinalRegister fr = new FinalRegister();
    fr.setVisible(true);  
  }
```

Now, After this I want after entering all the required data by the user and when user clicks to register button all the data of Previous `frame(Register)` and this `Frame(finalRegister)` should be saved to Mysql and for that I had done this behind register button.

```java
private void jButton_RegisterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                 
      Register rg = new Register(); 
      String name = Register.jTextField_Name.getText();
      String email = rg.jTextField_Email.getText();
      String contact = rg.jTextField_Contact.getText();
      String clas = (String) rg.jComboBox_Class.getSelectedItem();
      String section = (String) rg.jComboBox_Section.getSelectedItem();
      String subject = (String) rg.jComboBox_SubjectTeacher.getSelectedItem();
      String phstd = (String) rg.jComboBox_Contact.getSelectedItem(); 
      String enrollment = Register.jTextField_EID.getText();
      Date date = new Date(rg.jDateChooser1.getDate().getTime());
      String username = jTextField_Setusername.getText();
      String confirm_username = jTextField_Confirmusername.getText();
      String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Setpassword.getPassword());
      String confirm_password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Confirmpassword.getPassword());
      String Security_Question = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
      String Security_Answer = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Securityquestion.getPassword());
      String gender = "Male";
      if(Register.jRadioButton_Others.isSelected()) {
          gender = "Others";
      }
      else
          if(Register.jRadioButton_Female.isSelected()){
              gender = "Female";
          }

      if(verifyfield()){
          PreparedStatement ps;
          String sql = "insert into register values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";

          try {
              ps = javaconnect.getConnection().prepareStatement(sql);
              ps.setString(1,name);
              ps.setString(2,gender);
              ps.setDate(3,date);
              ps.setString(4, clas);
              ps.setString(5, section);
              ps.setString(6, enrollment);
              ps.setString(7, email);
              ps.setString(8, contact); 
              ps.setString(9, subject);
              if(ps.executeUpdate()!=0){
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Registerred Successfully","Information Message",1);
              }
              else{
              JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connectivity Error","Error Message",2);
              }
          } catch (SQLException ex) {
              Logger.getLogger(FinalRegister.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
          }
      }
```

this is the coding of verifyfield()

```
  Register rg = new Register();
  String name = Register.jTextField_Name.getText();
  String email = rg.jTextField_Email.getText();
  String contact = rg.jTextField_Contact.getText();
  String clas = (String) rg.jComboBox_Class.getSelectedItem();
  String section = (String) rg.jComboBox_Section.getSelectedItem();
  String subject = (String) rg.jComboBox_SubjectTeacher.getSelectedItem();
  String phstd = (String) rg.jComboBox_Contact.getSelectedItem(); 
  String username = jTextField_Setusername.getText();
  String confirm_username = jTextField_Confirmusername.getText();
  String password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Setpassword.getPassword());
  String confirm_password = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Confirmpassword.getPassword());
  String Security_Question = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
  String Security_Answer = String.valueOf(jPasswordField_Securityquestion.getPassword());
  if(name.trim().equals("")||email.trim().equals("")||contact.trim().equals("")||clas.trim().equals("")||section.trim().equals("")||
     subject.trim().equals("")||phstd.trim().equals("")||username.trim().equals("")||confirm_username.trim().equals("")||
     password.trim().equals("")||confirm_password.trim().equals("")||Security_Question.trim().equals("")||Security_Answer.trim().equals("")){
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Some Fields are empty.\nKindly Fill it","Warning",0);
  return false;
  }
  else{
  return true;
  }
}
```

[image: Screenshot of 1st Frame]

[image: Screenshot of 2nd Frame]

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: Please post the error log as well.

Comment: kindly see the error in the image